# Mouseover event not triggered on some child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover

So I have a menu item I need to trigger on mouseover:

```
<li class="nav-list valign browse">
   <a href="#" class="topnav-item text-small">
   Browse
   <span class="icon-menu"></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

The css for the span looks like:

```
  .icon-menu:before {
     content: "\e612";
  }

   [class*="icon-"]:before {
      color: #ff3200;
   }
```

If I set a jQuery trigger like:

```
  $(".nav-list").on('mouseover', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     ...
  }
```

The result is that whenever I mouseover the icon, the event is not triggered. It is triggered when I mouseover the 'Browse' word though or anywhere in the < li >. Is there a reason why? Am I doing something wrong? What would be the right way to do it?

**Edit:** Just found the mistake, it was actually a different problem. I had replaced on('click'.. by on('mouseover'.., so a 'mouseout' was missing to make the new code work properly. Just discussing it here made me realize I was on the wrong track. :)

Comment: Your code working correctly. See here :http://jsfiddle.net/7j5Vu/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger an event when the mouse gets hover the icon you should do it like this:

```
  //access .icon-menu instead of .nav-list
  $(".nav-list .icon-menu").on('mouseover', function(e) {
    alert("ok") 
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB62m/4/)

BTW you use `.icon-user` in your **CSS** and `icon-menu` in your **HTML**

Comment: I updated my post with the correct piece of css, bad Copy/Paste, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, Did my response answer your question ?

Comment: I believe you did. Just have to change `$('.nav-list .icon-menu')` to `$('.nav-list')` OP wants it triggered when mouseover the whole `li`

Comment: @metsales Changing $('nav-list .icon-menu') to $('.nav-list') brings us back to my original question :). There has to be some other mistake in my code, I am investigating now.